# similarity between bundle shift

Tags: operator-theory

Let $E$ be a flat unitary bundle of rank $n$ over a domain $R$ in $\mathbb{C}$. It is known that bundle shift $T_{E}$ is similar to $T_{\mathbb{C^n}}$ (which is the bundle shift corresponding to the trivial bundle $R \times  \mathbb{C^n}$).

I am struggling to fill up the details of the proof of the above statement.It is known that by Grauert's theorem there exist a holomorphic bundle map between the two bundle which is a isomorphism between those bundle.So the bundle map establish a module isomorphism between the holomporphic section of thosse bundle. But I am not able to show that  this map is bounded if we  restrict it to the space $H^2_{E}$.

Can anyone help me?